# Wordpress jQuery error &#038

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete:

```
<script charset="UTF-8">
    $(function() {
        var availableZtour = [<?php query_posts('category_name=AAAA&showposts=5&orderby=date'); if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>"<?php echo  the_title(); ?>",<?php }} wp_reset_query(); ?>];
        $( "#ztour" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableZtour
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the HTML, this echoes:

```
var availableZtour = ["Cycling &#038; Cooking","Snorkeling &#038; Tour",];
```

But this appears as this in the browser:

```
Cycling &#038; Cooking or Snorkeling &#038; Tour
```

I'm using `remove_filter ('the_title', 'wptexturize');`, but this doesn't work for `&#038;`

How do I make the code echo `&` and not `&#038;`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html-entity-decode), or fix the autocomplete plugin to process HTML entities correctly.

Comment: i'm add html_entity_decode to my code `var availableZtour = [<?php query_posts('category_name=AAAA&showposts=5&orderby=date'); if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>"<?php echo  html_entity_decode(the_title()); ?>",<?php }} wp_reset_query(); ?>];` but it's: #038 not '&'  i'm not lazy :( i'm don't fix it's.